# How to set the FBRequest delegate to nil in multiple different objects

Tags: ios, facebook, delegates

I'm using the Facebook sdk for ios and I'm facing an issue on how to safely set the delegate to nil. My facebook object is a property of the appDelegate and I'm using this object in multiple different objects to retrieve different information. So, say that object A, B and C conform to the FBRequest protocol and are set as the delegate of the facebook object. Now in the dealloc method of object A I want to make sure that object A is no longer a delegate, so I could do: facebookObj.delegate = nil. However, I feel that this would affect the other delegate objects B and C. Am I thinking correctly? Is there any way to remove only the object A from the facebook delegates without affecting objects B and C?
Hope the question makes sense.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an separate FBRequest object for each request that you fire off from your A, B and C objects, no? From what i understand, the FBRequest object only lives while the request is processing. Once its complete or fails the object goes away, no? Now of course, if you keep a reference to this request it will *look* like its there because you have an address to it but if you try sending messages it will crash (Unless using ARC with weak references which i doubt you are using).

Try this from each of your objects (A, B & C):

```
NSLog(@"FBRequest address %@", your_fbrequest_object);
```

And see if it always prints the same address or different ones.